# Link open left div

Tags: javascript, plugins, html, hyperlink

i have this link http://www.tgi.com.pt/link/tabSlideOut.html

and my idea is the link content open the left div.

But I can't doing the desired effect

any suggestion?

Comment: not clear what you are trying to explain here. do you want to add some link in contact box?

Comment: It worked for me. I clicked on Contact and it slid out to the right. That's not what you wanted? I'm on FF 3.6.8.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, i see -- you want the ***Content*** link to open the Contact thing. Well, I see your Content link (in footer (which is actually more of a header)) is:

```
     <a id="handlee" href="#">Content</a>
```

so, that doesn't seem like it would ever do anything.

You do have another Content link down below, but that appears to be incorrectly included in your slide_out_div. Perhaps that Content link is supposed to be up above in the footer section where the other Content link is?

Comment: The link on the second Content is: `http://link-for-non-js-users`, which doesn't appear to be a well-formed url.

Comment: All i need is the toogle btton